# Searching string for character not in array

Tags: performance, vb.net

I have a string which I want to check for characters other than those in this list {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ".", "i"} however this check gets run several thousand times a second.

I am therefore looking for the most efficient way of performing this check, what I have tried so far:

```
If Not System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(Input, "[^0-9\.i]") Then
```

This is equivalent to the code below which I have also tried

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(IsValidString())
    End Sub

    Private Function IsValidString() As Integer
        'Dim Input As String = "Hello World" 'This is Invalid
        'Dim Input As String = "13.4i+4" 'This is Invalid
        Dim Input As String = "13.4i" 'This is valid
        If Function()
            Dim IsValid As Boolean = True
            For Each Character In Input
                If Not {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ".", "i"}.Contains(Character) Then
                    IsValid = False
                End If
            Next

            Return IsValid
        End Function() Then
            Return -1
        Else
            'Do some other stuff
            Return 1 '
        End If
    End Function
End Module
```

I am looking for optimal performance possibly at the cost of readability as I am willing to write pages on how the code works and what it does if only I can speed up the execution of my app!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case (and many others), when it comes to performance, there's really nothing that beats the old trusty [For Next](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx) and [Select Case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) statements.

```
Private Function IsValid(input As String) As Boolean

    Dim index As Integer
    Dim length As Integer = (input.Length - 1)

    For index = 0 To length
        Select Case input.Chars(index)
            Case "0"c, "1"c, "2"c, "3"c, "4"c, "5"c, "6"c, "7"c, "8"c, "9"c, "i"c, "."c
                Continue For
            Case Else
                Return False
        End Select
    Next

    Return True

End Function
```

---

I've run a test, as seen in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8UHVcY) (Release build - Any CPU) with 10000 iterations and this is the result:

> { Name = IsValid1, Repetitions = 10000, Result = False, Time = 0,7359 }
> { Name = IsValid2, Repetitions = 10000, Result = False, Time = 58,787 }
> { Name = IsValid3, Repetitions = 10000, Result = False, Time = 106,5004 }
>
> { Name = IsValid1, Repetitions = 10000, Result = True, Time = 0,4382 }
> { Name = IsValid2, Repetitions = 10000, Result = True, Time = 42,1742 }
> { Name = IsValid3, Repetitions = 10000, Result = True, Time = 65,9497 }

```
Private Function IsValid2(input As String) As Boolean
    Dim validChars = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ".", "i"}
    Return input.All(Function(c) validChars.Contains(c))
End Function
```

```
Private Function IsValid3(input As String) As Boolean

    Dim IsValid As Boolean = True

    For Each Character In input
        If Not {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ".", "i"}.Contains(Character) Then
            IsValid = False
        End If
    Next

    Return IsValid

End Function
```

Comment: That's an impressive improvement!

Comment: If anyone is interested in *why* this is an order of magnitude faster, it's because the switch statement eliminates an entire loop. (The one that's hidden by the call to `Contains`.)

Comment: @RubberDuck Yup, the IL jump table is way more faster :)

Answer (score 6):

First we'll clean this up a bit, then we'll look at performance.

There is absolutely zero reason to be using an anonymous function. This is useful functionality that you will eventually want to call from somewhere else. As such, it deserves to be extracted into a proper method of it's own.

```
Private Function IsValidString() As Integer
    'Dim Input As String = "Hello World" 'This is Invalid
    'Dim Input As String = "13.4i+4" 'This is Invalid
    Dim Input As String = "13.4i" 'This is valid
    If IsValidString(Input) Then
        Return -1
    Else
        'Do some other stuff
        Return 1 '
    End If
End Function

Function IsValidString(Input As String) As Boolean
    Dim IsValid As Boolean = True
    For Each Character In Input
        If Not {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ".", "i"}.Contains(Character) Then
            IsValid = False
        End If
    Next

    Return IsValid
End Function
```

Next, let's forget entirely about the other `IsValidString()` method for a second and focus on the code we want to focus on. Watch your casing. It's terribly confusing to make local variables `PascalCased` just like your classes & methods. Local variables should be `camelCased`.

```
Public Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(IsValidString("Hello World"))
    Console.WriteLine(IsValidString("13.4i+4"))
    Console.WriteLine(IsValidString("13.4i"))
End Sub

Function IsValidString(input As String) As Boolean
    Dim isValid As Boolean = True
    For Each character In input
        If Not {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ".", "i"}.Contains(character) Then
            isValid = False
        End If
    Next

    Return isValid
End Function
```

We could go one step farther and Linq-ifiy it a bit into some very readable code.

```
Function IsValidString(input As String) As Boolean
    
    Dim validChars = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ".", "i"}

    Return input.All(Function(c) validChars.Contains(c))
    
End Function
```

---

But does it perform? Well, actually, yes it does. [I wrote some benchmarking code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f7P332) and it turns out that the Linq version out performs yours by quite a bit. I was kind of surprised by this, but here are the results.

> ```
> Sample Size: 100
> Original; Mostly Invalid: 10ms
> Linq; MostlyInvalid: 0ms
> Original; Mostly Valid: 0ms
> Linq; Mostly Valid: 0ms
>
> Sample Size: 1000
> Original; Mostly Invalid: 2ms
> Linq; MostlyInvalid: 1ms
> Original; Mostly Valid: 2ms
> Linq; Mostly Valid: 1ms
>
> Sample Size: 10000
> Original; Mostly Invalid: 25ms
> Linq; MostlyInvalid: 4ms
> Original; Mostly Valid: 25ms
> Linq; Mostly Valid: 23ms
>
> Sample Size: 100000
> Original; Mostly Invalid: 235ms
> Linq; MostlyInvalid: 41ms
> Original; Mostly Valid: 231ms
> Linq; Mostly Valid: 255ms
>
> Sample Size: 1000000
> Original; Mostly Invalid: 2408ms
> Linq; MostlyInvalid: 587ms
> Original; Mostly Valid: 2347ms
> Linq; Mostly Valid: 2083ms
>
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

As you can see, the Linq version nearly always outperforms your method on mostly *invalid* input. However, on mostly *valid* input, it performs roughly the same; it's sometimes better, sometimes worse. I suspect this is because the Linq version bails out of the check earlier on invalid input.

[Here's the final version of the benchmarking code.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6zULFW) It exceed's .NetFiddle's memory limits, so you'll need to paste it into a C# console program to see the results of the higher sample sizes.

If you're either uncomfortable with Linq, or *really* looking to just push the performance to the absolute best it can be, then we can just modify your original algorithm to return early when we know that the answer is false.

```
Function IsValidString(input As String) As Boolean
    For Each character In input
        If Not {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ".", "i"}.Contains(character) Then
            Return False
        End If
    Next

    Return True
End Function
```

This outperforms the both version above in *every* case, mostly valid or mostly invalid and it does it consistently each time I run the [updated benchmarks](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DDBoC7).

> ```
> Sample Size: 1000
> Original; Mostly Invalid: 2ms
> Linq; MostlyInvalid: 0ms
> Improved; Mostly Invalid: 0ms
> Original; Mostly Valid: 2ms
> Linq; Mostly Valid: 2ms
> Improved; Mostly Valid: 1ms
>
> Sample Size: 10000
> Original; Mostly Invalid: 25ms
> Linq; MostlyInvalid: 4ms
> Improved; Mostly Invalid: 3ms
> Original; Mostly Valid: 22ms
> Linq; Mostly Valid: 20ms
> Improved; Mostly Valid: 17ms
>
> Sample Size: 100000
> Original; Mostly Invalid: 242ms
> Linq; MostlyInvalid: 43ms
> Improved; Mostly Invalid: 33ms
> Original; Mostly Valid: 235ms
> Linq; Mostly Valid: 238ms
> Improved; Mostly Valid: 186ms
>
> Sample Size: 1000000
> Original; Mostly Invalid: 2479ms
> Linq; MostlyInvalid: 609ms
> Improved; Mostly Invalid: 336ms
> Original; Mostly Valid: 2358ms
> Linq; Mostly Valid: 2059ms
> Improved; Mostly Valid: 1704ms
> ```

---

***BUT........***

## Correctness

Is `0323.233.12.i` a valid string? Both your and my method says it is. Your regex also suffers from the same problem.

Comment: You should terminate the loop over the string immediately after finding an invalid char: isValid = False : Exit For. Or even: Return False.

Comment: Excellent answer, greatly appreciated! Also really good point about the multiple '.'s you are quite correct in that this is something I had overlooked. I have only been programming for two years, I still have a lot to learn! Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're very welcome @user4110980. I just updated the question one last time. You may be interested in it, even though the function needs to be corrected.

Comment: Because the strings that get passed to this method are generated by my program and not by user input I am relying on the exception throwing downstream as invalid 'input' values are very rare indeed.